# Match Algorithm Problem - Match offsetting positions

Tags: python, r

I am looking to create a match algorithm for allocating units of product between different individuals. I don't program for a living but can get it figured out with a little direction. So if I can get the get some direction on how to approach this in python/R/excel, I can easily figure it out.

Below is a picture of a description of what I am trying to do - I am trying to match two individuals for each product group.

[Data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfPuv.jpg)
Any help I can get is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify the what Short/Long means? Is it to denote who has too much (long) or not enough (short)?

Comment: Basically yes, long denotes someone who has excess and short denotes someone who has not enough. I am basically trying to match individuals where everybody comes to 0. (long =0, short =0)

Comment: Will there always be an equivalent number of overstocks and understocks? Or will there be leftovers? Also, can you split a shipment i.e. if a source has 100, send 50 to one place and 50 to another?

Comment: There will not be any leftovers - equivalent number of over and understocks always. Not exactly sure I am answering your question but essentially for each individual in the output the total number of units should be equal to the absolute value of number of units in the input. So, in the input C is 250 units and in the output C is 250 (100+150).

Comment: I happen to be working on a similar project. I will keep you posted if/when i finalise a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution in Python. The basic concept is that we sort from smallest to largest, pick whichever list has the largest first item, and then move through the other list summing up values until we have a transaction that can occur. Then we perform the transaction and remove the items involved. The pseudocode is:

```
Split into two lists for overstock or understock
Sort from smallest to largest absolute value
Perform easy transactions (i.e. Overstock at one location equals understock at another)
Perform dynamic partial transactions (i.e. Allows totals to be split between multiple locations)
```

Here is the code.

```
# Test data
current = [
    ["A", "AAA", 1, "Long", 100],
    ["B", "AAA", 1, "Long", 150],
    ["C", "AAA", 1, "Short", -250],
    ["D", "AAA", 1, "Long", 50],
    ["E", "AAA", 1, "Short", -50],
]

# Split by Long/Short
over = []
under = []

for line in current:
    if line[4] > 0:
        over.append(line)
    else:
        under.append(line)

# Sort by size of value
over = sorted(over, key=lambda x: abs(x[-1]))
under = sorted(under, key=lambda x: abs(x[-1]))

transactions = []

# Perform easy One-to-One transactions
i = 0
j = 0
while (i < len(over) and j < len(under)):
    if over[i][4] == abs(under[j][4]):
        transactions.append([under[j][0],over[i][0],  over[i][4]])
        over.remove(over[i])
        under.remove(under[i])
    else:
        if over[i][4] > abs(under[j][4]):
            j += 1
        else:
            i += 1

# Perform dynamic partial transactions
while len(over) > 0 and len(under) > 0:
    if over[0][4] == abs(under[0][4]):
        transactions.append([under[0][0],over[0][0],  over[0][4]])
        over.remove(over[0])
        under.remove(under[0])
    else:
        if over[0][4] > abs(under[0][4]):
            transactions.append([under[0][0],over[0][0],  abs(under[0][4])])
            over[0][4] -= abs(under[0][4])
            under.remove(under[0])
        else:
            transactions.append([under[0][0],over[0][0],  over[0][4]])
            under[0][4] += over[0][4]
            over.remove(over[0])

# Show results
for transaction in transactions:
    print(transaction)
```

Output is:

```
['E', 'D', 50]
['C', 'A', 100]
['C', 'B', 150]
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask any questions you have!

Comment: Thank you so much! The logic makes full sense to me. One quick question tho - If I have to run this output for multiple set of products AAA, BBB etc and have it in the output - then I need to do a for loop where this logic runs for each product. Does that make sense?

Comment: In essence, yes. Might require a bit of creativity,  but you should be able to enclose the whole program in a loop that runs it once per unique product.

Comment: Here is the [extended version](https://pastebin.com/UkjaFHJ9) that should allow you to perform the same operation over multiple different items. I've thrown in some more test data so you can see the results.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate this sooo much!

Comment: No worries mate. All the best, and welcome to Stack Overflow!